# disable scroll bars in C++ console

Tags: c++, console

![C++ single console window ][1]
 1: the white space around after removing border
  2: how to remove scroll bars

code is

HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();

```
LONG x = SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, 
    GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE
    && !(


    WS_BORDER | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_DLGFRAME


    )
    ));


SetWindowPos(hwnd,NULL,700, 50, 300,300, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the console screen buffer to be the same size as the console window. 
You can get the size with GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo and set it with SetConsoleScreenBufferSize.